# AdMediator - UWP - What's What

Tags: windows-10-universal, windows-store

Using the AdMediator control **could not be any more confusing**. (Universal App)

**Set one of keys, app ids etc.**

Microsoft help starts with adding a connected service which adds a .config file. with keys, ids and who knows what else to the project.

**Set two of keys, app ids etc.**

Dev Center Dashboard add ad unit (Required Step) - another set.

**Set three of keys, app ids etc.**

By dragging the control to the designer!

Now I have 3 possible different keys

Do I need an ad unit for each control I add? (possible 4 sets now)

Do I really need a Mobile version? (choice when adding an ad unit, how about 5)

Do I really need an AdDuplex control ? (if AdDuplex is chosen in connected services - now it's getting crazy)

After all is said and done - does the project .config file need to be manually edited?

Can someone give me the run down on how to say, add 2 controls to a Universal App( one per page) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 1 application id for **each** of ad provider.

You need **at least** 1 ad id for **each** of ad provider.

If you only use MS ad (formerly PubCenter), you need to use the set of ids from Dev Center **only**. **Remove AdDuplex if you are not need it** (its **optional**).

> Do I really need a Mobile version?

No. Its optional.

> does the project .config file need to be manually edited?

No, but if you want to change it, you can do it even after submiting, from dashboard in Dev Center.

Comment: What/Where is the key that should be used along with the id?

Comment: what key are you talking about ? My code is

`<Universal:AdMediatorControl x:Name="AdMediator_05A7C1"
                                     Grid.Row="1"
                                     Width="480"
                                     Height="80"
                                     Margin="0,0,0,48"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                     Id="xxxxx"/>`

dont change `.config` file. It is surposed to be generated automatically.